# Treat TypeScript modules as Objects

Tags: typescript, amd

Well, this was working in Typescript 0.8.3 but as they said in "breaking changes" modules can only be used as namespaces.
the javascript implementation of modules is just another object (closure). So, is there any way to have the ability to treat imported modules as objects in TypeScript?

Here is an example:

```
//Module.ts
export function SomeFunc(){
}

//app.ts
import moduleA = require("Module")
var anotherRef = moduleA;           //this is caught as error!
```

Using TypeScript 0.8.3 I could pass the `anotherRef` to any method or even Knockout bindings to use the module reference. but typescript 0.9.x prevents that.

thanks

Comment: restart visual studio / make sure you have ts 0.9.1 installed, uninstall web essentials :) one of these should help

Comment: What error are you getting? I'm using TS 0.9.0.1 and this works for me?

Comment: Sorry for replying late, well, yes you can place it in a variable but when you want to export it using `import a = require('A'); export var b = a;` it fails. Well maybe the problem was not related to treating the module as a variable. (sorry for confusion). but do you know why it fails? (error: `Exported variable 'b' is using inaccessible module 'A'.`)

Comment: I know that using the new syntax I should export the module like this: `export import a = require('A')` but I do not really understand why there is such a limitation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me in TS 0.9.0-1. The limitation you mention is for internal modules and it does not affect external modules (amd/commonjs) like the one you have. i.e. it is only for modules defined with the module keyword as:

```
module SomeMod{
    export var foo = 123;  
}
```